# Spark Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_4_piece0 of broadcast_4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got the following error: `Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_4_piece0 of broadcast_4` while submitting spark job

Anyone can help me out?

See full error below:

> java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get
>   broadcast_4_piece0 of broadcast_4
>
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1178)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
>
> at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:65)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
>
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get
>   broadcast_4_piece0 of broadcast_4

Comment: need more information like code snippet and what you are trying to do here? Also  this error will come when you are joining dataframes.